# Only returning 0.0 when entering value into entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

When entering value into entry tabs only return 0.0 for both could anyone help I've tried `IntVar` and `StringVar`

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
point_label = Label(window, text="Amout of Points").pack()
point_entry = Entry(window, text="points", bd=5).pack()
Games_label = Label(window, text="Amout of games played").pack()
Games_entry = Entry(window, text="games", bd=5).pack()

def calculate ():
    Games_entry = DoubleVar()
    point_entry = DoubleVar()
    point_entry = point_entry.get()
    Games_entry = Games_entry.get()
    print(Games_entry, point_entry)

Button(window, text="Submit", command = calculate).pack()


window.geometry("800x600")
window.title('Arena Point Calculator Chpater 4 Season 2')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `calculate()` function creates _brand new_ widgets, so of course their values default to 0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to declare and `pack()` your widgets on separate lines. `pack()` and the other geometry manager methods all return `None`. As written, `point_label`, `point_entry` and the other widgets are all equal to  `None` which isn't what you want (you'd end up calling `None.get()` which will cause an error!)

Next, you can just use `get()` directly on the `Entry` widgets. The values you get will be strings; if you need their values to be integers, you can convert them using `int()`

```
point_label = Label(window, text="Amount of Points")  # fixed typo
point_label.pack()

point_entry = Entry(window, text="points", bd=5)
point_entry.pack()

# FYI, these names should start with lowercase letters
# uppercase names are reserved for Classes and "CONSTANTS"
games_label = Label(window, text="Amount of games played")  # fixed typo
games_label.pack()

games_entry = Entry(window, text="games", bd=5)
games_entry.pack()


def calculate():
    point_entry_value = int(point_entry.get())
    games_entry_value = int(games_entry.get())
    print(point_entry_value, games_entry_value)
```

Lastly, it's important to note than the `calculate` function isn't doing any verification on the values, so you'll get a `ValueError` exception if the values can't be converted to integers, i.e. if you type in "Banana" or something like that.